# Executar servlet antes de carregar index.jsp

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Estou tentando executar meu servlet antes de carregar a index.jsp, pois as informações contidas na index vem de uma consulta no banco de dados. Tentei usar

```
<jsp:forward page="/servlet"/>
```

mas não deu certo. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você precisa de um Filter :)

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia Guilherme.

São varias as formas de se atingir o objetivo que você pretende. Utilizar um Filter como o @DilneiCunha sugeriu é uma das formas.

Outra forma também interessante é editar a tag `<welcome-file>` no seu arquivo de configuração **web.xml** (*Se seu projetor estiver usando um, claro)*.

O seu arquivo de configuração `web.xml` ficará mais ou menos assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>servlet</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Note que:

- `/servlet` seria o mapeamento para a Servlet que você quer usar para preencher o `index.jsp`.
- Se no seu `web.xml` já existir a tag `<welcome-file>` preenchida com `index.jsp` é necessário substituir para o mapeamento da sua Servlet. *(Não se esqueça de retirar o `/`)*

Por fim, na sua Servlet, basta dispachar a requisição para o `index.jsp`. Assim, dentro de `index.jsp`, você terá acesso ao `request` que pode conter os dados que você obteu por meio de sua lógica dentro da Servlet.

Sua Servlet ficará mais ou menos assim:

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //Executar sua lógica para obter os dados
        //...

        // Dispacha a requisição para index.jsp
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response); 
    }

}
```

Pronto. Seu projeto irá funcionar com esse *workaround*.
Não se esqueça de sempre buscar soluções alternativas para os problemas.

Espero ter ajudado. Um abraço.

Comment: Obrigado Andrew Ribeiro.
Foi o mesmo caso:
Eu precisava iniciar a página home e-commerce, porém, antes, precisava ir no banco de dados para buscar os produtos para expor na tela inicial.